# Unable to RDP to Azure VM despite following troubleshooting techniques from multiple online posts

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-standard-manage-portal) tutorial, I successfully created a `Load Balancer` and an `Azure VM`, but I'm unable to `RDP` connect to this `VM`. I've tried several online articles and forums but still no success. I'm getting the exact same error (shown below) whether I try to connect via `Azure Portal` or `PowerShell`. So, I thought I should show my VM's networking settings to see if that can give someone a clue here:

**Please NOTE**:

1. I can successfully RDP from my Home PC to my WORK PC, so, I guess, it should not be Client RDP software related issue.
2. Per Microsoft's suggestions, I've tried Restarting my VM, and 
   [Resetting Remote Desktop Services Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-rdp)

**My VM's Networking Settings** [You can click on the image to zoom it in if you need to]

[image]

**Error that I always get**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not work because there is no endpoint to allow RDP connection to your VM.

You have to add a new rule with priority less than 65000 that allow inbound connection to port 3389. Once this is done, you will be able to connect normally.

Sometimes, it takes around 30 seconds for the rules to reflect.

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). I had to dig a little bit to find out how to add a new rule after a `VM` has already been created.